まえ for sentence ending
Ive been watching a series and some of the (male) characters end their sentences with mae. It seems to be an assertion of some sort but im not quite sure.
For example:

これからも頑張って続けたまえ


病院に残りたければ残りたまえ

Ive searched for ending particles but i run into the usual particles like そ、ざ、だな, etc.
Thanks for your answers in advance!

@Leebo I think it might, ill check more into it, thanks
